# Can I set the same IP address for every ethernet port of a server?

Tags: router, static-ip

I have a server (mostly files and build jobs) that I'd also like to use as a router. There's already a firewall in place in front of it to restrict traffic, so I'm not worried about that. It's also just a home setting so I'm not super worried about attacks to begin with.

Every router I've ever seen, no matter what LAN port you connect to, you can access it by the same IP address. In essence, each port has the same IP address. So I'm thinking the same should be possible with the server, correct? Obviously the WAN port is an exception to this.

Comment: Each interface (eg Ethernet and WiFi) needs a separate IP address: if you enable DHCP on each interface it will set up that interface IP as the default route and the primary DNS. There is probably DHCP software that will allow connections through multiple interfaces, though its availability may depend on the server's OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not *exactly* as you describe. In short, you're *not* asking to use the server as a router; you're actually asking to use it as a bridge/switch.

### Why

> Every router I've ever seen, no matter what LAN port you connect to, you can access it by the same IP address. [...] Obviously the WAN port is an exception to this.

The configuration you describe is only common for multifunction home routers. (Key word being "multifunction" – they aren't just routers, they're several devices in one.)

In your description, internally the router sits between two *networks* (WAN and LAN), and the LAN side leads to a built-in *switch*. So the reason you get the same IP from all four yellow ports is because they are actually switch ports.

However, dedicated routers work the opposite way: every port is separate and belongs to its own network, unless you manually bridge them. (Remember that routers are gateways between networks, so it makes sense.) But using a router for bridging is overkill – a dedicated switch does the job better.

(That said, some devices – both home gateways and enterprise "L3 switches" – are more flexible and allow each port to be either part of a switch *or* used independently for routing.)

### How

Most PC operating systems *do* support bridging multiple ports, as well as routing between subnets.

#### Bridging

Bridging a single subnet is easy. On Linux, you can create a bridge using `ip link` or the older `brctl`, then set it as "master" of all Ethernet ports. On Windows, just select the ports and choose "Bridge interfaces".

The server's IP address then needs to be configured *on the bridge*, while those individual ports remain addressless.

(Though note that the performance won't be necessarily good – your "router" probably has a dedicated switch chip, but your server will have to use its main CPU. Meanwhile, an actual gigabit switch is $20.)

#### Routing

Routing multiple subnets is a little more complex (especially if you also want e.g. DHCP), so it's best left for later. If you do decide that you need the server to be a *router*, post a separate question with the topology you want described.

Comment: Oh. I just assumed it would be easier to set up since that's what "routers do". This probably explains the troubles I've been having. I'll set each independently then.

Comment: It's quite easy to set up, but you're looking in the wrong place.